# Intellij idea javascript code assist/completion not working even after adding the libraries

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, karma-jasmine

I just came to know about this cool feature of intellij idea where in settings you can libraries and code assist/completion will work for the library.

I am looking out for code assistance for karma-jasmine test cases.

I have followed up the steps, you may verify that by screen shot:

Screenshots:

[Intellij-Ideaadded-karma-jasmine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ermK9.png)

[karma-jasmine config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SxKv.png)

Still neither I am getting the code completion nor highlighting feature.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get coding assistance for Jasmine (e.g. describe, it, etc), try to  instal stubs for Jasmine (not karma-jasmine).

Comment: It was 'jasmine-DefinatelyTyped' from community stub which I used.